# Изменить функцию влияние на цену товара

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

```
   $ss = $this->db->query("SELECT tb01.jan - sum(tb02.quantity)  AS test
    FROM oc_product AS tb01 
    LEFT JOIN oc_order_product AS tb02  ON tb01.product_id = tb02.product_id
    LEFT JOIN oc_order AS tb03 ON tb02.order_id = tb03.order_id 
    LEFT JOIN oc_customer AS tb04 ON tb03.customer_id = tb04.customer_id
    WHERE tb01.product_id = '{$pid}'
    AND tb04.customer_id = '{$cid}'  LIMIT 1");
    $omg = $ss->row['test'];
    $iss = $ppp->row['isbn'];
    if($omg<='0') {}
    if($omg>'0') {
if($cart['quantity']<$omg) {

   if($iss>'0') {
   $price = $price-$price/100*$iss;
}
```

Есть поля $iss(% скидки) и $omg(количество скидок минус - количество купленного товара пользователем именно этого товара).
Ситуация такая что если есть 2 шт скид товара то при добавление третьей шт цена для всех 100% идет как можно повлиять что бы цена плавно менялась? товар 100р 2шт скид 40%, то есть 2 шт = 120р + 1шт то будет 220р ! 
А сейчас сразу в 300 р преврашается
[вот файл](https://opencartforum.com/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=252937)

[image: Вот 2 шт со скидкой]

[image: Вот при добавлении еще 1 шт без скидки что происходит]

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что у Вас есть таблицы `oc_product` в котором вы храните свои товары, в данной таблице у Вас есть `количество скидок` и `процент скидки`? Или у Вас для скидок отдельная таблица?

Comment: нету все в oc_product но даже больше скажу что есть таблица oc_order_product откуда я минусую кол купленного товара от jan количество товара скидочного и вывожу то что получается в условия будет ли скидка или нет

Comment: Данный код срабатывает при открытии корзины с товарами? или же при оформлении заказа уже?

Comment: При корзине и при оформлении и то не везде сумма итого меняется а есть сумма товара в оформлении она стоит по цене без новой скидки и я хочу место найти общее и воздействовать на него только это будет после того как решу эту дилему сверху

Comment: Я просто не вижу смысла в вашем коде. Согласно коду в файле, формируется массив `product_data` со всеми товарами в корзине. В данном массиве, у каждого продукта есть такие поля `price` и `total`, дак вот Вам нужно поле `total`. Сейчас оно рассчитывается так `($price + $option_price) * $cart['quantity']`, а должно быть `(($price + $option_price) * $cart['quantity']) - (((($price + $option_price) * $product_query->row['isbn'])/100) * 'количество скидок')`

Comment: вы гениальный человек) эта логика спасибо большое

Comment: Да не за что)  сначала проверьте будет ли работать) А то уже сколько времени не можем решить Вашу проблему со скидками

Comment: Ну я уже все сделал осталось везде корректно отобразить цены и сделать это изменение мол 2шт(скид) плюс 3шт без скидки цена и пусть проходит, в данный момент у меня при добавлении без скидки шт товара цена для всех без скидки становиться

Comment: НУ тогда хорошо. Удачи Вам

Comment: Не помогло( мне нужно на цену для каждого товара воздействовать что бы при скидке, а не на общ общая и так правильно работает) У вас нет идей? 
@Евгений Николаев

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86004/discussion-between---and-bistore-bi-group).